# Validate HMAC from Shopify Webhook (Using Hapijs)

Tags: javascript, shopify, hapi.js, hapi

I'm trying to validate Shopify's HMAC in a webhook. This is how my controller looks:

```js
  newOrder: {
    payload: {
      parse: false
    },
    handler: function(request, reply) {
      const hmac = request.headers['x-shopify-hmac-sha256'];
      let generatedHash = crypto
        .createHmac('sha256', utils.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET)
        .update(JSON.stringify(request.payload))
        .digest('base64');

      if (generatedHash == hmac) {
        console.log("Validated");
      } else {
        console.log("Not validated");
      }



      console.log(hmac, generatedHash.toString(), utils.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET)
      reply().code(200);
    },
    auth: false,
    notes: 'Shopifys new order webhook',
    tags: ['api'],
    id: 'newOrder'
  }
```

But the `hmac` is never equal to the `generatedHash`. I think it's related to req.rawBody (from Express) but I don't know how to get the same payload from Hapijs or I'm missing something.

I'm using HapiJs v14.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `payload.parse` as false in route's config and use `request.raw.req` for getting the raw body

Comment: ```request.raw.req``` is not a buffer neither a string and Hapi throws error. If I use a ```pre``` in the controller I can use ```request.payload``` which is a Buffer if you have configured:

```
    payload: {
      output: 'data',
      parse: false
    }
```

Anyway, the generated ```generatedHash``` is not equal to ```hmac``` 

Still don't know which I'm missing here.